# How do I pass parameters into a sed command

Tags: json, sed

I am trying to make a function that takes parameters to be used in a sed command.

```
replace_json_str() {
    x=$1
    sed -i -e 's/\("$2":"\)[^"]*\("\)/\$3\2/g' $x
}
```

Original json: `{ "USER":"root" }`

Usage: `replace_json_str test.json USER pi`

Expected json: `{ "USER":"pi" }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell will not expand variables in single quotes. Try this:

```
replace_json_str() {
  x=$1
  sed -i -e 's/\({ "'"$2"'":\)"[^"]*" }/\1"'"$3"'" }/g' $x
}
```